# Error during run the program runtime error

Tags: python, django

These are apps installed in my django project. the apps with  vip_number.* are inside the innerproject folder.  but i got the issue here that my apps are not installed in seetings.py where as they are already there

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
        'jet',
        'jet.dashboard',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'vip_number.users',
        'vip_admin',
        'vip_number.base',
        'vip_number.categories',
        'vip_number.category_tag',
        'vip_number.category_numbers',
        'vip_number.number',
        'vip_number.paytm',
        'vip_number.subscribers',
        'vip_number.homeimages',
        'vip_number.testimonial',
        'vip_number.faq',
        'tagconstants',
        'sekizai',
        'vip_number.wawebplus',
        'contact',
    ]
```

error

```
    (djangoenv) PS E:\download\VIP number\vip_number> python manage.py runserver
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 244, in create
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 246, in create
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'base'. Check that 'vip_number.base.apps.BaseConfig.name' is correct.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\download\VIP number\vip_number\manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\download\VIP number\vip_number\manage.py", line 16, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 637, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 622, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 327, in run
    autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 41, in watch_for_template_changes
    for directory in get_template_directories():
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 14, in get_template_directories
    for backend in engines.all():
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.engine = Engine(self.dirs, self.app_dirs, **options)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.template_libraries = self.get_template_libraries(libraries)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 93, in get_template_libraries
    loaded[name] = import_library(path)
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 317, in import_library
    module = import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\download\VIP number\vip_number\templatetags\custom_tags.py", line 3, in <module>
    from vip_number.users.models import User
  File "E:\download\VIP number\vip_number\vip_number\users\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 133, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "E:\download\VIP number\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 113, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
```

error i face

```
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.        
(djangoenv) PS E:\download\VIP number\vip_number>
```

Comment: Each app should have an `apps.py` file, are those there and setup correctly?

Comment: yes all setup is done right related to apps,, but some of the apps inside the root project directory what is the correct way to install them,  like some apps inside the VIP number root project where our settings.py file exists,, they installed like 'vip_number.testimonial', for now